# Vite Cache busting with query param instead of file name

Tags: config, vite, rollupjs

In Vite, is it possible to use a query param for cache-busting (instead of a hash in the file name)?
My current config looks like this:

```
import { fileURLToPath }        from 'node:url';
import { URL }                  from 'node:url';
import { defineConfig }         from 'vite';
import vue                      from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        vue(),
    ],
    base: '/frontend',
    build: {
        outDir: '../www/public/frontend/',
        emptyOutDir: true,
        rollupOptions: {
            output: {
                entryFileNames: 'assets/[name]-[hash].js',
                chunkFileNames: 'assets/[name]-[hash].js',
                assetFileNames: 'assets/[name]-[hash].[ext]',
            },
        },
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)),
        },
    },
});
```

When I change the assetFileNames to use the hash as a url param like this I get compile errors

```
assetFileNames: 'assets/[name].[ext]?v=[hash]',
```

The errors look like this:

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open ' ... some absolute path here ... \site\www\public\frontend\assets\someCss.css?v=82315f25'
```

Is there a way to tell Vite not to use the params in case it's referencing the file like this or is there maybe another way to add the hash as a query param?

Comment: @marcel Unfortunately not :(

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue, and I wrote a Vite plugin to implement this functionality. It works well for me, and I hope it helps you too.

```js
import { rename, writeFile } from 'fs/promises'
import path from 'path'
import { Plugin } from 'vite'

const ENTRY_FILE_NAME = 'index.html'
const NEED_TRANSFORM_EXT: readonly string[] = ['.html', '.js', '.css']
const HASH_LENGTH = 8

interface FileInfo {
  fullName: string
  name: string
  hash: string
  ext: string
}

export default function (): Plugin {
  return {
    name: 'transform-hash',
    async writeBundle(outputOptions, bundle) {
      const outputDir = outputOptions.dir!
      const cntByFileName = new Map<string, number>() // Dealing with duplicate file names
      const fileInfoByPath = new Map<string, FileInfo>()
      for (const filePath of Object.keys(bundle)) {
        if (filePath === ENTRY_FILE_NAME) {
          continue
        }
        const fileInfo = extractFileInfo(filePath)
        const cnt = (cntByFileName.get(`${fileInfo.name}${fileInfo.ext}`) ?? 0) + 1
        cntByFileName.set(`${fileInfo.name}${fileInfo.ext}`, cnt)
        if (cnt > 1) {
          fileInfo.name += cnt
        }
        fileInfoByPath.set(filePath, fileInfo)
      }
      for (const [filePath, bundleInfo] of Object.entries(bundle)) {
        if (!NEED_TRANSFORM_EXT.includes(path.extname(filePath))) {
          continue
        }
        // @ts-ignore
        let codeOrSource: string = bundleInfo.code ?? bundleInfo.source
        for (const fileInfo of fileInfoByPath.values()) {
          codeOrSource = codeOrSource.replaceAll(
            fileInfo.fullName,
            // "ext=.xxx" is used to ensure compatibility with Vite's determination of resource types
            `${fileInfo.name}${fileInfo.ext}?${fileInfo.hash}&ext=${fileInfo.ext}`
          )
        }
        await writeFile(path.join(outputDir, filePath), codeOrSource)
      }
      for (const [filePath, fileInfo] of fileInfoByPath) {
        await rename(
          path.join(outputDir, filePath),
          path.join(outputDir, `${path.dirname(filePath)}/${fileInfo.name}${fileInfo.ext}`)
        )
      }
    }
  }
}

function extractFileInfo(filePath: string): FileInfo {
  const fileName = path.basename(filePath)
  const ext = path.extname(fileName)
  const nameWithHash = path.basename(fileName, ext)
  return {
    fullName: fileName,
    name: nameWithHash.slice(0, -(HASH_LENGTH + 1)),
    hash: nameWithHash.slice(-HASH_LENGTH),
    ext
  }
}
```

vite.config.ts

```js
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import vueJsx from '@vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx'
import transfromHash from './plugins/transform-hash'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue(), vueJsx(), transfromHash()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  }
})
```